# How properly test credentials used by Azure SDK client are valid

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-java-sdk

I'm trying to create a function that given Azure credentials check if they are valid.

In this case, I'm taking ADLS account name and account key credentails.

The Azure Java SDK does not provide an API for this, os I'm doing the following manually

```
def testConnection(account: String, accountKey: String): Boolean = {
  val storageConnectionString = s"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${accountName};AccountKey=${accountKey}"
  val storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString)
  val client = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient()
  Try{ client.downloadServiceProperties() }.isSuccess
}
```

the problem is `downloadServiceProperties()` is relatively slow, it may take a minute or so. Are they other faster options to check if the user ADLS credentials are valid ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [DefaultAzureCredential Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-java-stable) and then call `getToken` to get the connection token. If no token is retrieved, user is not authenticated.

Take into account, that the user may be logged but does not have rights to perform the operation.

Comment: This seems interesting, thought I cannot find this class, I have this dependency `"com.microsoft.azure" % "azure-storage" % "8.6.5"`

Comment: You need this: ``com.azure:azure-identity:1.1.2``